# pandas problem. Try to save a csv with datetime but got error

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

index = ["1","2","2"]

data = {"A":"a","B":"b","C":"c"}

columns = data.keys()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

dateTime = str(datetime.datetime.now())[0:19]

fileName = (r"D:\user\test%s.csv"%dateTime)

df1.to_csv(fileName)
```

Comment: Anyone know what am I doing wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please edit your post - Proper format it, add the error traceback and some more information about what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have `:` colon in your file name

Use:

```
dateTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H_%M_%S")
fileName = (r"D:\user\test%s.csv"%dateTime)
```